# Binding Issue WPToolkit ListPicker with SQL Server CE 3.5 DataContext Class Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datacontext, listpicker, sql-server-ce-3.5

Well, well, this is my very first question in StackOverflow! I've been using this site since ages but I never had to ask something because I always found the answer in someone else's question lol Apparently this is not the case anymore lol.

Anyway, I'm trying to bind a list of a custom class (that is decorated to be used with the `DataContext` that manages a local SQL Server CE 3.5 database - natively included in Windows Phone 7.5) to a `ListPicker` control from the WPToolkit and strangely I can't see the value of the element I bound in the `ListPicker` (I made sure the list is populated).

Here's the class:

```
[Table(Name = "Rubriques")]
class Rubrique
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, DbType = "TINYINT", CanBeNull = false)]
    public Byte Id { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "NVARCHAR(40)")]
    public String Nom { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `DataContext`:

```
class IntermediaireDataContext : DataContext
{
    public IntermediaireDataContext() : base("Data Source='isostore:/IntermediaireBDD.sdf';")
    {
    }

    public Table<Rubrique> Rubriques
    {
        get { return this.GetTable<Rubrique>(); }
    }
}
```

Here's the code I use to bind the list to the `ListPicker`:

```
using (IntermediaireDataContext context = new IntermediaireDataContext())
{
    rubs = (from x in context.Rubriques select x).ToList<Rubrique>(); //rubs already exists
    RubListPicker.ItemsSource = rubs;
}
```

Here's the XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="RubListPicker" SelectionMode="Single" FullModeHeader="Rubriques">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}" FontSize="16"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

The list of `Rubrique` rubs gets populated and is set as `ItemsSource` to `RubListPicker` and if I remove the `Text="{Binding Nom}"` of the `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate` I can see the name of the class `MyNamespace.Rubrique` in every element in the `ListPicker`.

I can't figure out what is the problem with the data binding... Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I'm using the last version of WPToolkit 4.2012.10.30 from NuGet in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Regards,

Ali

---

### EDIT

I found the solution and it made me laugh hard lol.

I had to change de security level of my class Rubrique; When I did set it to public everything worked fine.

Actually, the `ListPicker` had access to the `List<Rubrique>` but could not access the value of each `Rubrique`.

A good one to remember for the future: Always check the security level of your classes/attributes/methods when using external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first question ever in StackOverflow and I get to answer it myself: Like A Boss :D

So the trick was to make my class public so it can be accessed by the ListPicker control from WPToolkit ;)

Cheers!